# error: failed in converting 7th argument `g' of _lbfgsb.setulb to C/Fortran array

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, gradient

Suppose

```
    def evaluateFunc(params):
        ...
        return err, grad
```

where `params` is a vector of `N` real values, `err` is a real number and `grad` is a vector of 2 real values.

```
    params = numpy.random.rand(X.shape[0]+1)
    bounds = np.append([(0,None)]*X.shape[0], [(None,None)], axis=0)
```

When I called the following function

```
params, minval, infos = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluateFunc, params, bounds=bounds)
```

I got the following error:

```
error: failed in converting 7th argument `g' of _lbfgsb.setulb to C/Fortran array
```

Why am I getting that error? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

If I remove the parameter `bounds=bounds`, then I got the following error:

```
failed to initialize intent(inout|inplace|cache) array, input not an array
```